# Modifying multiple Lists inside a function and returning it in Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I have a List of type [T] and [B] in scala, with an object e of type E.

I want to make a function that accepts those three parameters:

```
def doSomething(t : List[T], b List[B], e : E) {
 ... }
```

However I realise that List is immutable, and anything passed to a function is considered as val (not var). But I need to modify t and b and return the modifications back to the caller of the function. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I can't go and change the list to array... Because I've been using it everywhere and the file is so big..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should modify `t` and `b` in a functional way using higher order functions like `map`, `filter`,... and put the result of them into new `val`s (e.g. `modifiedT`, `modifiedB`). Then you can use a `Tuple2` to return 2 values from the method.

```
def doSomething(t: List[T], b: List[B], e: E) = {
  // somehting you want to do
  val modifiedT = t.map(...).filter(...)
  val modifiedB = b.map(...).filter(...)
  (modifiedT, modifiedB) // returns a Tuple2[List[T], List[B]]
}
```

In the calling method you can then assign the values this way:

```
val (t2, b2) = doSomething(t, b, e)
```

Of course it depends on what you mean with "modify".
If this modification is complicated stuff you should consider using `view` to make calculation lazy to move the time of calculation to a later point in time.

Comment: You need an `=` between `e: E)` and `{` if you're going to return something.

Comment: You are correct Rex, thanks. I don't know how often I forget this small `=` in Scala...